Pipfile.lock error when installing packages with pipenv
I am trying to create a virtual environment with Python 3.11.4, with the following packages: numpy 1.25.2, pandas 2.0.3, requests 2.31.0 and jupyterlab 4.0.5, where I can run jupyterlab and use jupyter notebook.
I created my virtual enviromnent fine.
When I tried to install my packages with their specific version, in runs but no Pipfile.lock is created. I get this error message:
Installing numpy...
Resolving numpy...
Added numpy to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Installing 1.25.2...
Resolving 1.25.2...
Added 1.25.2 to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠙ Locking packages...False
<console width=124 ColorSystem.TRUECOLOR>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anaconda3/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 52, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 92, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 207, in install
    do_install(
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 234, in do_install
    raise e
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 209, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 649, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/routines/lock.py", line 67, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 859, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 723, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!

I can install numpy without specifying the version and it works, but when I try to specify the version it does not. This happens for all of the packages I am trying to install.
I have tried editing the pipfile directly then using pipenv sync, and it says it is synced but when I run pipenv graph, the versions I need are not in my global environment.
I have also tried pipenv lock to create the lock file, but when I try installing my packages when the versions specified, I get the same "failed to lock Pipfile.lock!" message. I have also used verbose and the same thing happens.
Why won't these package versions install- is it a dependencies issue? I wouldn't think that woulld create Pipfile.lock problems. This is also for an assignment so I need those specific packages in my venv.

I also tried using sudo pipenv and I got the same failed to lock Pipfile.lock message

py -m pip pipenv install --ignore-pipfile

Thank you! I tried that but I still get the same error message. I probably committed some cardinal sin when I was creating my venv

Try this pip install -p   and pip freeze -p different_pipfile
